# Azure DevOps - not able to unlink from default solution file setting in ASP.NET build settings

Tags: c#, build, azure-devops

I am working with a C#.NET solution that contains a few dozen projects (it probably qualifies as a 'monlith,' since many of the projects are cross-dependent on many of the other projects). The majority of these projects use pre-.NET Core WebForms technology with some MVC thrown in here and there. We're hoping to create Azure DevOps pipelines for the individual projects within the solution to use for automated builds/releases.

What I'm finding in Azure DevOps, using the classic editor, is that when I create a build, specify the repo, then choose the "ASP.NET" template, the "Parameters" textbox to specify the .sln file does not have an ellipse next to it and the box is inactive and locked on "***.sln". Also, the little chain icon above the textbox does not include an option to "unlink" the fields (which is how I've done this in the past elsewhere). So it appears that I'm stuck building only the entire solution.

Is this a situation where I can only use YAML? I believe that I can do something similar to (solution)\project.csproj? Are any configurations possibly blocking the "unlink" (I haven't found them yet) or are there other alternatives to this approach? Or do I build the entire thing and selectively publish and release the separate projects?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was an easy one. I talked to a DevOps admin and he said I was not in the Build Administrators group, so he added me and now I see the "Unlink all."

Answer (score 0):

Please go **Pipeline** section of your build definition. There listed parameters which maps to the solution setting in the VSBuild task, then click **Unlink** which beside Parameter.

[image]

Comment: My problem is that I don't have that "unlink all" link in my Azure DevOps UI. I'll check again today, but it wasn't there. If it was, that would solve everything.

Comment: yes, it's not there. Could this be a configuration or permissions issue? I'll look into that as well.